# Error CS1525: Unexpected symbol

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

I m using:

```
Xamarin 5.8.3 (build 1)
Xcode 6.3.1
```

Having the above error in this line:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
```

In one of my .xib.

The error is:

```
Error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `<' (CS1525)
```

Any idea where this weird Error/Bug coming from?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you already try to clean your project and (re)build it? Did you delete the .xib followed by adding a new one? Same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to compile a .xib as C# source code.

That won't work.

Right-click the file in the solution explorer, and select `Build Action` -> `InterfaceDefinition`.